# Linq check if list is in another list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I am currently working on a project where I have warehouse. The warehouse is divided into a lot of zones (A-J). Furthermore, the warehouse contains a lot of products which are spread over the different zones. When a customer buys products from the web shop, it comes in as an order. An order contains several products and which zones these products are in.

In addition, I have set up a shortest path from zone A to every other zone. This is to minimize the time, the workers have to walk when they pick the products from the shelves.

So, for the path, I have a list of strings which contains a path, i. e. A, B, C, I.
Also, I have list of orders, where the zone property is also a list of strings.
Say i have a list of orders containing the following zones:

Order 1: A, C

Order 2: C, I

Order 3: B, C

Order 4: A, F

Is there a way, using Linq, where I can get all the orders where the zones are equal to the zones in my path?
So for instance in this example, I would only get orders 1, 2 & 3. Not 4, because 4 contains a zone F which is not in the specified path.

I tried the following which didn't work, because it also returned order 4:

```
var jobs = (from j in db.jobs select j).ToList();
List<string> path = new List<string> (){"A","B","C","I"};
var jobsInPath = jobs.Where(x => x.zones.Intersect(path).Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: @fubo Doesn't .Contains only apply for a string? When I try it in VS, it says "Cannot convert from List<string> to string"

Comment: ok i didn't know the data structure, I expected `x.zone` to be a string

Comment: `orders.Where(o => o.Zones.All(z => path.Zones.Contains(z)))`

Comment: Can you show us data structure of `Job`?

Comment: check if Zones contains ALL zones from order. That will eliminate Order 4, as F is no in path .

Comment: var placeorders = from ord in orders where path.Any(t => ord.Zones.Contains(t)) == false select ord

Comment: @AndreiTătar Thank you, this worked. Can I mark a comment as accepted answer?

Comment: var filterorders = (from odr in orders where path.Any(p =>  odr.zones.Contains(p)) select odr).toList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Orders.Where(x=> x.Zones.All(z=>Path.Zones.Contains(z))).ToList();
```

Your Solution does not work because:

```
var jobsInPath = jobs.Where(x => x.zones.Intersect(path).Any()).ToList();
```

Here Intersect returns the common strings... Order 4 also contains A hence for order 4, It will return A and Any() expression will be true.